# Рисование мышкой

Tags: java

Задумал переделать виндовый *Paint* на *Java*. Т.к. я не очень давно изучаю джаву хотелось бы узнать какие способы рисования мышью предусмотрены в этом языке? Рисование простых примитивов я уже изучил и опробовал, теперь хочется знать как правильно рисовать произвольные изображения.

Comment: А GUI через что реализован?

Comment: @Tim Leyden, есть замечательный метод paint у окна JFrame, а также есть замечательные события Mouse. Хотя при таких банальных вопросах, врятли у вас удастся реализовать хотя-бы половину возможностей Paint.

Answer (score 1):

Самая простая программа для рисования выглядит так (код частично позаимствован от [сюда](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123947/extremely-simple-paint-program-in-java-tips-for-making-it-run-smoother)) :

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
  private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 800;
  private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 800;
  private static final Color BACK_COLOR = Color.WHITE;

  private int x1, y1, x2, y2;
  private Graphics g;


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint program simple");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new PaintPanel();
    frame.add(panel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }


  private PaintPanel() {
    setBackground(BACK_COLOR);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT));

    MyMouseHandler handler = new MyMouseHandler();

    this.addMouseListener(handler);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
  }

  private class MyMouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        x1 = e.getX();
        y1 = e.getY();

        g = getGraphics();

        x2 = x1;
        y2 = y1;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x1 = e.getX();
        y1 = e.getY();

        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        x2 = x1;
        y2 = y1;
    }
 }}
```

В этом коде, создается фрейм, к нему добавляется панель с белым фоном. К этой панели добавляется обработчик событий мыши. При клике мы запоминаем координаты мыши, а при перетаскивании, берем текущие координаты и предыдущие и чертим между ними черную линию.